# installed font not working in ec2 in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, fonts, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I have downloaded font by running

```
wget http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/download/amatic
```

inside my ec2 instance. Then I created a .fonts director and unzipped those files inside it. Then I `ls .fonts` and there were the font files. Then I ran `fc-cache -f -v` and it gave me this output

```
    /usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 3 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 5 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-cns1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-gb1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-japan1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-japan2: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-korea1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu: caching, new cache contents: 6 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/type1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts: caching, new cache contents: 35 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/home/ubuntu/.local/share/fonts: skipping, no such directory
/home/ubuntu/.fonts: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 3 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/home/ubuntu/.local/share/fonts: skipping, no such directory
/home/ubuntu/.fonts: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/var/cache/fontconfig: not cleaning unwritable cache directory
/home/ubuntu/.cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/home/ubuntu/.fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
fc-cache: succeeded
```

Then I went to see in the browser if the font had been applied but it is still not applied. When I run `fc-list` I can see that my font is listed there but it is not being show in my rails app.however i found out that when I ran a ruby script `ruby test.rb`, in which was the same code for image manipulation , it worked fine and the fonts was also the one i wanted but the only problem is in my rails app. I have restarted my rails app but the problem is still persisting.

I am using that font for image manipulation.

This is my code

```
txt = "Sushant"

overlay = Magick::Image.read("stamp.png").first

 title = Magick::Draw.new
if txt.length <= 7


  title.annotate(overlay, 0,0,120,200, txt) {
    self.font_family = 'Amatic SC'
    self.fill = 'white'
    self.pointsize = 160
  }
else



  title.annotate(overlay, 0,0,0,200, txt) {
    self.font_family = 'Amatic SC'
    self.fill = 'white'
    self.pointsize = 155
  }

end

  img = overlay.write('newimg.gif')
```

Comment: The browser you are testing this with, is it running on the same server that you are installing the fonts on?

Comment: @mbaird yes, I have installed the fonts on my local environment as well as in the production environment. in the production environment I wrote a ruby script that did the same image manipulation and it gave me the right font in the image but the rails app that was suppose to do the manipulation is not showing the right font in the image.